# Regex matching EOL character within a string

Tags: regex, eol

I'm trying to find LF characters that appear between double quotes. The text file I'm searching has field-value pairs in this format

```
    msgid "text 1"
    msgstr "text 2"
```

I'm trying to find if LF characters appear within text 1 or text 2 strings. I have tried `"[^"\r\n]*\n[^"\r\n]*"`
but it just picks up `" msgstr "`

Comment: what regex flavor are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex :

```
if ($subject =~ m/"([^"\r\n]*?[\r\n]+[^"\r\n]*?)"\s*$/m) {
    $result = $1;
}
```

When applied to these strings :

```
msgid "text 1 " 
msgstr "text 2"
msgstr "something with new 
line"
```

Will produce this output :

```
something with new 
line
```